# Passport session clear req.session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, passport.js

I'm coding a session with NodeJS, when I get the user connection first create a session.client with the MAC ADDRESS, so far so good, but then I ask to the client if he want to continue and login on the app with social -network like Facebook, Instagram, Tweeter or Google+, and then when the user is redirected to the social login it back with other session from passportjs and clear al my init data of session and I lost the client information. So, I tried to change the name of the data in session, session.data, session.test, session.whatever but always happen the same, when I test and the passport redirect me and back to my domain, the session is clean and it change with new data from passportjs, any one know what's happen here? any idea how to solve this?

the code run perfectly, the problem is the session when go and back to // the social login, it clear my init data and back with the passport data. // I need my init data to continue working!

this is just an extract of code. It works

```js
'use sctrict'

const https = require('https'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path'),
  morgan = require('morgan'),
  logger = require('express-logger'),
  express = require('express'),
  favicon = require('serve-favicon'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  methodOverride = require('method-override'),
  passport = require('passport'),
  // config files
  port = 443,
  mongodbConfig = require('./config/mongodb-config'),
  session = require('express-session'),
  keys = require('./config/keys'),
options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('./config/ssl/server.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./config/ssl/server.crt')
  },
  cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
  loginAPRoutes = require('./routes/loginAPRoutes'),
  passportSetup = require('./config/passport-setup'),

  app = express()


// MongoDB - Mongoose connection
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.Promise - global.Promise
mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + mongodbConfig.mongodb.route + '/' + mongodbConfig.mongodb.db, {})
  .then(() => console.log('db connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))




// config
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')




// middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public/img/', 'favicon.ico')))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.use(session({
  secret: 'cybor-cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}))
// initilize passport
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())




// Main routes
app.use('/guest', loginAPRoutes)

app.use('/auth', loginAPRoutes)




// Run the server https
https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, () => {
  console.log('NodeJS Server Started... splice.pro is running!')
})

router.get('/s/:site', (req, res) => {

  data = req.query
  data.site = req.params.site


  req.session.data = data


  console.log('===== session ========')
  console.log(req.session)
  console.log('====== session END =======')



  res.render('login')
})



/////////////// GOOGLE AUTH ////////////////

// route for google login
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: ['profile', 'email']
}))

// route for google and redirect
router.get('/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
    if (!req.user) {
      res.redirect('/guest/s/site')
    } else {

      /////////// here comes the new session from passport :( //////
      ////////// and lost the first data of my session /////

      console.log(req.session.data)

      //////////////// this show the session with info of user ///////
      /////////////// but req.session.data is lost ///////////

      res.redirect('/guest/startconnection')
    }
  }
)

/////////////// GOOGLE AUTH END ////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, well, well.... I found my problem, my external site redirect me to my server with the ip and when the request of passport login redirect , it back to the domain name, that's why it generate a new session id ... A long day but at the end I found it !